# How to find out which programs are taking up alot of memory?

Tags: sudo, ram, disk-usage, memory-usage

I've been getting messages that I have exceeded my quota limits. I am new to Linux and am not sure what to do. With windows, I could easily just go to Control panel, add/remove programs, and uninstall whatever programs I don't use that use alot of disk space. How do I do the same thing in linux?

I've already tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` but I get the message `sudo: apt-get: command not found`. Also, `du -sk * | sort -nr | head -10` only shows the directories that have taken up a lot of disk space, not which programs are taking up a lot of disk space

edit: My department told me I could baobab to graphically see which programs are taking up alot of memory. It says to go to "Analyzer → Scan Filesystem", but I don't see that anywhere

Comment: memory (RAM) and disk space are not the same thing. You can remove programs from the software center. Hard to know why your disk drive is full from what you posted.

Comment: Quota exceeded? Do you control your system or is it externally administered? What is the output of `lsb_release -cd`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out which programs were the cause that certain directories now take up much space?

Comment: yes, I want to find out which programs are taking up alot of space

Comment: My department told me I could baobab to graphically see which programs are taking up alot of memory. It says to go to "Analyzer → Scan Filesystem", but I don't see that anywhere

Comment: That's very different! If you have a complicated program that consists of many large program files, and does not need much memory when working. And a program with one small program file, that shows many images as thumbnails, and keeps a huge mass of thumbnails as image files for next use. Which of them do you want to find?

Comment: Yes, `baobab` is great. It shows a file tree at the left, and a special circular size graph at the right, after calculating all the sizes for the disk.

Comment: Just want to locate programs that take up alot of memory, for example, Matlab

Comment: Ok - the software was installed with normal Ubuntu tools, not compiled manually?

Comment: I still think your search is pointless. Quotas are usually set on home directories, you should look at you home directory first.

Comment: If your "department" set up a quota for you then they had reasons.  If that interferes with your actual work then I would suggest contacting the "department" and having them send over a technician to sort the issue.

Comment: what about htop

Answer (score 0):

There is `wajig`, a tool that adds another layer of more highlevel command line UI to the `dpkg-...` and `apt-...` tools.

It has just the feature you need:

```
$ wajig large
```

lists the largest installed packages,  counting the total size when unpacked and installed. That may be much larger than the `*.deb` file - it depends on file count and sizes instrange ways.

The command above also lists installed size for packages that were installed, and later uninstalled, keeping the configuration files.

To leave them out, use grep to find the lines with `installed`, at the end of the line (`$`), and as a complete word - `\b` marks a word start or word end.:

```
$ wajig large | grep '\binstalled$'
```